# htaccess rule to add country parameter to URL with Cloudflare geolocation

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, geolocation, cloudflare

I've used stackoverflow extensively during my coding endeavours and thank you all for providing such a fountain of knowledge.

I would like to implement a mod_rewrite/htaccess rule that will add the visitor's country as a parameter to *any* URL, *if* the country is different from AT. Geolocation is done through Cloudflare.

Like: Visitor from CH visits https://www.example.com/blabla => https://www.example.com/blabla**?country=CH**

I'm not too savvy in htaccess rewrites and end up with an infinite loop / server error. 
I believe it's a correct *RewriteRule* part that's missing for me. Here's my code:

```
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "(.*)$" Country=$1
RewriteCond %{ENV:Country} !AT
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?country=%{ENV:Country} [R,L,QSA]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to add another RewriteCond, that checks that `country=…` is not already in the query string of the requested URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.
For anyone facing the same problem, the solution was:

```
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "(.*)$" Country=$1
RewriteCond %{ENV:Country} !AT
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !country
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?country=int [R=308,L,QSA]
```

I did not find a way to append the *specific* country code as I couldn't reference the ENV:Country in "RewriteRule" but "int" for all non AT works well for me.